# can I use variables in packer templates user_data_file

Tags: variables, packer

Can I use variables defined in my web-packer.json template to the file in user_data_file.

I am using user_data_file to setup wimrm and add a user to the administrator group. Before installing the webserver.

Some of the web-packer.json template

```
"builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "vpc_id": "{{user `vpc_id`}}",
      "subnet_id": "{{user `subnet_id`}}",
      "associate_public_ip_address": true,
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
      "region": "eu-west-1",
      "source_ami": "ami-40003a26",
      "instance_type": "c4.xlarge",
      "ami_name": "cms-sitecore",
      "communicator": "winrm",
      "winrm_username": "{{user `winrm_username`}}",
      "winrm_timeout": "30m",
      "user_data_file": "./bootstrap-aws.ps1"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "./install/",
      "destination": "C:/install"
    },
    {
      "type": "powershell",
      "inline": [
        "Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Asp-Net45,Web-Static-Content,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-Http-Errors,Web-Http-Logging,Web-Stat-Compression"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. `user_data_file` is not a template and hence not interpolated. You have to use `user_data` for that or preprocess your `user_data_file` outside of Packer.